# How to make React show errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Im facing an issue with React (16.13.0), tt's not showing any usable errors, instead I get this:

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

Accoording to the message I should use the debug build to see the error, however I already am (AFAIK). React dev-tools seems to agree with me:

> This page is using the development build of React.

I'm using `webpack@4.42.0` with `mode` set to `development`. I also use `@babel/preset-env@7.8.7` and `@babel/preset-react@7.8.3`

**webpack.config.js**

```
const argv = require('yargs').argv;
const paths = require('./build/paths');

const jsName = `${paths.package.name}-js`;

/**
 * Webpack configuration
 * Run using "webpack" or "gulp js"
 */
module.exports = {
    // Path to the js entry point (source).
    entry: {
        [jsName]: __dirname + '/' + paths.jsEntry,
    },

    // Path to the bundles.
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/' + paths.jsDir, // directory
        filename: '[name].js', // file
        chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/static/bundles/',
    },

    // Use --production to optimize output.
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            // JavaScript
            {
                test: /.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
        ]
    },
};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is kind of embarrassing. The problem was that my errored component had a a (IDE generated) import to a the production build of React causing this behavior:

`import {useContext} from 'react/cjs/react.production.min';`

Should of course be:

`import React, {useContext} from 'react';`